# Understanding $ \forall x \exists y \forall z P(x, y, z) $

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$ \forall x \exists y \forall z P(x, y, z) $

**Domain** $D$: {1, 2}

For this formula to evaluate to **true**, would it be correct to say that the predicate $P$ would need to evaluate to **true** for the following tuples of terms?

$ (1, e_1, 1) $
$ (1, e_1, 2) $

$ (2, e_2, 1) $
$ (2, e_2, 2) $

Where $ e_1 \in D $ and $ e_2 \in D $

Comment: Not how I would state it.  But I'd say there must be an $e_1$ and an $e_2$ where they are true.

Comment: Maybe it would help to rewrite it as $\forall x: [x\in D \to \exists y: [ y\in D \land \forall z: [z\in D \to P(x,y,z)]]]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

You have to show that such $e_1$ and $e_2$ exists to make them all true.

Comment: Thanks, would it also be correct to say that $e_1$ and $e_2$ can refer to the same object in the domain i.e.      $e_1$ = $e_2$?

Comment: Yes but need not be

Comment: They could be but they don't have to be.  There is some $E$ where $(1, E,k)$ is true for all $k$.  And there is a $G$ where $(2, G, k)$ is true for all $k$.  But there is no reason to assume $E$ and $G$ are the same.

Comment: It coulld be possible that $(1,1,1),(1,1,2), (2,2,1),(2,2,2)$ are all true but $(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(2,1,1),(2,1,2)$ are all false.  .... or that $(1,2,1)$ is true  and $(1,2,2)$ is false while $(2,1,1)$ is false ad $(2,1,2)$ is true.